# Display content of a list in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, list

I am new in Angular. I am creating a component in which I am creating a list of int. An example of the content of the list is 13,14,15,22,23,24.
I want to display this content on screen in a specific way. I want the continiously integeres to be in one line and the others in the second line. For example I want this:

13:00, 14:00, 15:00     button

22:00, 23:00, 24:00     button

I am trying this but I don't want a continious list, I want two parts of the list.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let int of listindexdisabled">{{int}}:00 </li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: If it angular2 then

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let int in listindexdisabled">{{int}}</li>
        </ul>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below code

```
<ul> 
    <li *ngFor="let int in listindexdisabled">{{int}} : 00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is going to throw an error: Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we try to set up two loops with a SlicePipe to iterate on a portion ( 13 -> 15 and second loop 2 -> 24 )?

If you have non dynamic list and you list will always need to be cut at a certain index , this should help you

https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

```
<ul>

    <li *ngFor="let int of listindexdisabled | slice:0:3">
        {{int}}:00
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let int of listindexdisabled | slice:3:6">
        {{int}}:00
    </li>
</ul>
```

otherwise , i think that this should works

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let int of listindexdisabled">
        <li *ngIf="int < 22">
            {{int}}:00
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let int of listindexdisabled">
        <li *ngIf="int > 21">
            {{int}}:00
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My list is being created dynamic, so I don't now the specific integer in which I should slice every time

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of what you could do: [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1cgdzw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

And in case stackblitz is not working, here is the code :

.html :

```
<ul *ngFor="let chunk of displayedValues">
  <li>
    <span *ngFor="let value of chunk">{{value}}:00 - </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { getAttrsForDirectiveMatching } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  values = [13,14,15,18,19,22,23,24];
  displayedValues = [];

ngOnInit(){
  this.customChunk();
}

  customChunk(){
    let array = [];
    this.values.forEach(val => {
      if(array.length === 0 
      || val === array[array.length-1] + 1){
        array.push(val);
      } else {
        this.displayedValues.push(array);
        array = [];
      }
    });
    // add the last chunk
    this.displayedValues.push(array);
  }
}
```

The idea is to rework your array into an array of chunk made by numbers that follow themselves. Then you just have to do a loop inside a loop to display your values.